# As of July 2016, is there any new improved research on predicting French grammatical gender?

Tags: reference-request, french, gender

Please advise me if there are better research methods; I only searched for Related Articles on Google Scholar to the only 2 recent papers that I know:

[Cited Articles](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&um=1&ie=UTF-8&lr&cites=18424126486931447452) of [*French gender assignment revisited*](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00437956.2005.11432551) (2005) by Don Nelson.

[Cited Articles](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=40&hl=en&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&cites=3193462087085624954&scipsc=) of [*Predictability in French gender attribution: A corpus analysis*](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00437956.2005.11432551) (2005) by Roy Lyster.

Because Lyster analysed only 'A corpus
of 9,961
nouns  appearing  in
*Le  Robert  Junior  Illustré*', I hope that analysing a broader corpus (if anyone has done one) would ameliorate the results.

Comment: Simple rule: if the word in Latin is masculine or neutral, then the corresponding word in French will be masculine; if the word in Latin is feminine, then the corresponding word in French will be feminine.

Comment: @KennyLau *mer* < *mare*? *dent* < *dēns*? Not that simple.

Comment: Well, for most of the time. Rules always come with exceptions, don't they.

Comment: I don't think that this question is off-topic: Gender prediction looks like a task for computational linguistics.

Comment: @KennyLau French also comprises Word Forms of Germanic or Frankish origin though, and not only Latinate.

Comment: @Timere That's a fair point which I haven't considered.